# How I can monitor SQL Server 2012 databases to determine the security privileges that are called by different processes

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Is there any tool that can identify the SQL privileges or roles that are being called on query by query basis. We need to know which ones are being used at each time on a Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Have you looked at using SQL Server Audit for this yet?

Comment: This is very nice doc on auditing if you have enterprise edtn http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SQL Activity Monitor**. This will show the current queries executing in your SQL Server instance with below details

- SPID
- Login
- Database Name
- Task State
- Command
- Application
- Wait time
- Host Name and many more under **PROCESSES tab**

Also you can have a look on

- Resource waits
- Data File I/O
- Recent Expensive Queries